# Move settings.json to a different folder for Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-data-studio

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/settings?view=sql-server-ver15#settings-file-locations) Azure Data Studio looks at `%APPDATA%\azuredatastudio\User\settings.json` on Windows for the settings.

**Can I tell Azure Data Studio to use a different folder for the settings.json file?**

Why? I recently lost my Windows profile. I do not have a backup of all the connections and server groups I had defined in ADS. I'd like the settings.json file to be in a folder that is synced to the cloud so that I have a backup in the future.

Comment: Here is an extension for syncing settings to a Gist. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync. It says it works with ADS.